# Formal algebraic explanation of an error involving the root of a perfect square

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In the course of finding a volume by integration I had to factor a trinomial into a perfect square. I was dealing with two distances which I will refer to as $a$ and $b$. Previously I had determined that $a < b$, but during the algebraic simplification I lost track of what the symbols represented. I factored a trinomial as $(a – b)^2$, but I then had to take the root and I simply represented that as $(a - b)$ instead of $-(a - b)$. Basically, I had taken the absolute value but symbolically what remained was the original, negative, difference.

I would like to know how to view the error in a formal algebraic sense. Presumably, I ignored the fact that $\sqrt{(a-b)^2} \neq (a-b)$ but $\sqrt{(a-b)^2} = |(a-b)|$. How should I have approached the aformentioned operations when divorced from an applied context? Should I have split 
$|a - b|$ into the two cases $a - b < 0$ or $a - b > 0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a general sense, if $x = (a-b)^2$, then we have $\sqrt x = a-b\ \text{or}\ \sqrt x=b-a$. So yes, split the cases and solve.